# wkhtmltopdf fails only on local files with error HostNotFoundError

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I'm having some trouble with a new install of wkhtmltopdf v0.12.1 64bit on CentOS6

This works perfectly:

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://google.com/ temp.pdf`

But the following command fails with ***HostNotFoundError*** (where domain.com is the domain of the php file running the shell script):

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://domain.com/ temp.pdf`

The same is true for any html file on the domain. Domain.com is resolving normally via a web browser. Also, trying to convert other webpages on different domains which are hosted on the same server works fine.

Any ideas what might be wrong? I suspect something surrounding the server firewall or the user account under which php runs but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It could be related to the links to the resources on the page. If `wkhtmltopdf` does not understand the protocol (as it thinks) it jumps to `http://` and can not load elements of the page. Look at https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf/issues/24 Show the html code you are trying to convert.

Comment: Thanks Cherry but it fails for all html files, even the most basic ones on the domain.I've updated the question now with more details.

Comment: What is happening if you do `ping domain.com` from the same host? I think this is DNS related problem, that has nothing to do with wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Thanks Antoan, it could very well be a DNS issue. The domain is forwarded from another server using an A record pointing to this IP. The ping seems to work fine tho: `60 packets transmitted, 60 received, 0% packet loss, time 59616ms`. Again, the command DOES work with html files on other domains on the same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching today I found a solution for this problem. It turns out it has the same root as a common issue running `file_get_contents()` on a local file. Here is the fix:

Modify `PHP.ini` to **enable** the following:

```
extension = php_openssl.dll  //remove the ; to uncomment (enable) this line

allow_url_fopen = on
```

Hopefully this will help someone else out!